# Internationalization for user defined input

Tags: internationalization, playframework, yaml, playframework-2.1, ebean

I'm trying to build a `localization` for user defined input. Example: a user could define categories like soccer but in several languages.

The model entity could have a filed something like this:

```cs
    @ManyToMany     
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "locale", insertable = false, updatable = false)     
    public Map<String, L18n> titles;
```

I'd like to store the localized strings like this:

```cs
@Entity
public class L18n {

    @Id
    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public Integer id;

    public String key;

    public String locale;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    public String text;

}
```

We use **yaml** to store the testdata:

```cs
    category:

        - !!models.Category
                ...
                titles: 
                    - !!models.L18n
                         key: soccer


    l18n:

         - !!models.L18n
                key: soccer
                locale: de-CH
                text: fdfdfsee

         - !!models.L18n
                key: soccer
                locale: fr-CH
                text: dlfkjsdlfj
```

With this solution I'm getting this error:

```cs
    [error] Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: No suitable constructor with 1 arguments found for interface java.util.Map
    [error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructSequence.construct(Constructor.java:574)
    [error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182)
    [error]     at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:296)
    [error]     ... 65 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you've defined titles as a map, but don't use the YAML mapping syntax to define it.  [YAML Collections](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963)

I think the syntax for titles should look like the example here using langauges: [YAML Dictionary Example](http://ansible.cc/docs/YAMLSyntax.html)

```
titles: 
    soccer: - !!models.L18n
                key: soccer
                locale: de-CH
                text: fdfdfsee
    football: - !!models.L18n
              ...
```

If you change the format of your .yml file so that the L18n instances are defined first and use references, the YAML spec calls them [Alias Nodes](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2786196), you could make your titles look a lot more streamlined:

```
l18n:

     - &soccerDE !!models.L18n
            key: soccer
            locale: de-CH
            text: fdfdfsee

     - &soccerFR !!models.L18n
            key: soccer
            locale: fr-CH
            text: dlfkjsdlfj

category:

    - !!models.Category
            ...
            titles: 
                soccerDE: *soccerDE
                soccerFR: *soccerFR
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I implemented some kind of workaround but I'll check it out late when I have time..

Comment: No problem.  I'm by no means a yaml expert: I spend more time cursing the, IMHO, unhelpful error messages and syntax than effectively writing or debugging, but I did something similar a couple weeks ago.